# How to execute a single line from a paragraph in Apache Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I tend to group similar actions in one paragraph, but each action can take a long time. Is there a way to execute only one line within a paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, Zeppelin does not provide this option to execute single lines from a paragraph. Refer [this link.](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.3/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html#paragraph)